# Linear chain Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, potential-energy, phonons

In Ziman's *Electrons and Phonons* book, he starts describing phonons with a linear chain. On Page 7, Eq. 1.3.6, he gives the potential energy as

$$ V = \frac{1}{2}g\sum_l{(n_{l+1}-n_l)^2} $$

where $g$ is a force constant, and $n_l$ is the displacement of the atom located at position $l$ in the chain.

Again on Page 7, Eq. 1.3.8, he writes the potential energy as:

$$ V = \frac{1}{2}g\sum_l{2n_ln_l-n_{l}n_{l+1} - n_ln_{l-1}} $$

Is this a typo? If you expand the square in the first equation, you do not get the second equation...

Comment: They are equivalent since they differ only for a relabelling of the terms in the summation.

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions are equivalent if you write them out for a chain of atoms. Try writing them out for a chain of 3 atoms, where the first and third atom are connected by periodic boundary conditions. You'll see that both expressions are equivalent, but the first expression just as terms that look like $2n_ln_{l+1}$, which also come about in the second expression if you sum over all atoms. It's not a simply matter of expanding the square.